# How to Send mobilepush for specific contactkey or an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios, react-native, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

I've integrated Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile Push in my react-native app.

When user logged in I'm setting a contact key.

When I looked in the platform, the specific deviceId is being shown with the email as well and I can send a push to the deviceId. But I'm not able to find the way to send the push for the contact key. I'm a bit lost there.
But is there anyway I can send the push notification to a specific contactkey or an email ?

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To send push notification to a specific contactkey or an email you can create list for specific contact key. on the mobile push platform go to contact. Yo should see two tabs (All contacts & Lists). Go to Lists tab and create List (Filtered List). After that You should see attribute library with all predefined and custom attributes. go to system data > contacts > drag and drop contact key > set the condition and enter specific contact key to which you want to send push notification. Click on done and save as filter (give some name to that list to identify). When you will create push message you need to select that list to send push. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't see `system data` in the dropdown in filtered list.
And how can I connect this to the Data Extension in salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Thidasa you need to:

1. Go to contact builder
2. Mobile Lists tab
3. On the right blue button "Create Mobile List"
4. Select channel "MobilePush" and type "Filtered"
5. Filter for your user

Also note when sending to a Contact in SFMC you are targeting all devices that are associated with this particular contact. It's not possible to target only specific devices.

Comment: Thank you @marketing-cloud.net . However the issue is the user I'm setting is not tagging to the user in salesforce.

eg : I have an my contact in salesforce as `abc@gmail.com` . If I set it as the contact key, should that user be tagged in salesforce side ? Else am I missing anything ?
Thank you